# is it possible to pass Null value via Post / Get? (PHP)

Tags: php, get, http-post

Is it possible to pass Null value via Post / Get?

By null, I mean something that will return true on `isset()` but false on `empty()`.

Reason is, I want to know if I need an extra check on `$_GET` where I'm checking the following:

```
if (isset() && !empty()) {
    // do stuff
} elseif (isset() && empty()) {  // In other words, omit this one.
    // do other stuff
} else {
    //foo bar
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: you mean as in `null` data type? i don't think so, it comes up as strings, combining `isset` and `empty` is superfluous, `!empty` should suffice, unless you'd expect `'0'` as valid

Comment: @Ghost - yeah, i meant null data type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a GET variable is not present (i.e. *script.php*), you will get:

- `isset($_GET['var']) = false`
- `empty($_GET['var']) = true`

If it is present but has no value (i.e. *script.php?test=*), you will get:

- `isset($_GET['var']) = true`
- `empty($_GET['var']) = true`

Thus testing that `isset($_GET['var']) && !empty($_GET['var'])` is enough to guarantee that your GET variable exists and has a proper value.

Comment: Thanks. just needed a second confirmation.

Comment: It's not looking like a way exists to determine if the param is null or an empty string.